# Пунктуация, несколько предложений

Tags: пунктуация

1. > У самого даже челюсть отвисла () с таким воодушевлением женщина костерила своего мужа.

Перед "с" должно быть тире или двоеточие?

2. > Моя проблема, которую я породил и теперь неспособен решить.

Нужна запятая перед "и"?

3. > Жаль только, что я в этом деле ничего не понимаю и все может пойти крахом.

Насколько я понимаю, в данном случае "жаль только, что" выступает общим второстепенным членом предложения и запятая между частями не требуется?

4. > Просто раз (,) и все.

Нужна ли запятая?

5. > А если еще хоть один раз прогуляешь () я тебя не допущу к сдаче! А если такой тупой, что не можешь решить простейшей задачи () иди на первый курс!

Я точно знаю, что если в БСП подразумевается условие, то нужно ставить тире. Но тут-то союз присутствует, хоть и не полный. Что ставить: тире или запятую?

6. > А это значит, что, сколько бы ты его отсюда не прогонял — если, конечно, ты найдешь способ — столько он и возвращаться будет.

Верно ли расставлены знаки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Лучше тире**, без увеличенной паузы: У самого даже челюсть отвисла  — с таким воодушевлением женщина костерила своего мужа.

2) **Однородные сказуемые или однородные придаточные (два способ объяснения)**: Моя проблема, которую я породил и (которую я) теперь **не способен**  решить.

3) **Однородные придаточные:**  Жаль только, что я в этом деле ничего не понимаю и (что) всё может пойти **прахом.**

4) **Просто раз, и всё.**
Они так быстро мелькнули ― раз, и всё. [И. Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)]

5) **Это СПП, составной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО**, но местоименная часть может опускаться:
А если еще хоть один раз прогуляешь,  (то) я тебя не допущу к сдаче! А если такой тупой, что не можешь решить простейшей задачи, (то) иди на первый курс!

6) **Перенесенная запятая:** А это значит, что, сколько бы ты его отсюда не прогонял — если, конечно, ты найдешь способ, — столько он и возвращаться будет.

Comment: А если так: Моя проблема, которую я породил и теперь связан с ней до конца своей жизни. Запятая не будет требоваться?

Comment: А какая разница? Я породил и связан - однородные сказуемые, одиночный союз И.  Сравнить: Это моя проблема, которую я породил, и теперь я связан с ней до конца жизни.  Это сложное предложение с подчинительной и сочинительной связью, запятая ставится.